# Is it possible to change seperator color of tableView in a Today Widget?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode-6.2

Is it possibble to change the color of separators of a UITableView in a today widget? If yes how does it work? I've tried to set the color in the attribute inspector and programmatically `self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.yellowColor()` but the color wont change.

One more thing: I just recognized that the length of the separators is a bit higher than the ones of the calendar widget for example, so is it possible to change the length too?

**Update**

I've just figured out, that the seperator lenght can be changed via the Inset if I set `self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 3, 0, 11);` the length is the same as the calendar where the 3 in the Inset is the left side and 11 the right one. Higher value means less seperator length.